# Placing words directly under or above other words

Tags: html, css

I wish to do the following within `div` tags:

[image]

The words will be coloured differently using `span`s.

I will be given some text in a text box and via JavaScript I will need to dynamically update to `div` to show something like the above.

**What is the best way to do this?**

Will it involve a monospaced font?

Will it involve writing "hidden" text?

I wish to do entire paragraphs in this manner.

This might seem weird but the research I'm doing requires me present certain words from a given text with multiple colours and I think this might be a nice way of conveying this information.

Updating the text in the text box will update the following variables, and in turn I will need to convert these two variables into something like the image above.

```
text = "I am under the text above me and there is lots more text to come./n I am even moving onto a new line since I have more text"

color_per_word_position =  {0:green, 1: red, 2: cyan, 4: yellow, 5: red, ...}
```

Comment: If the words are always the same as the words above/below, then hidden looks like the way to go

Comment: if by hidden text do you mean hiding the text with the background hex code? if so I wouldn't do that because when someone selects that area of text it will become highlighted and look weird.

Comment: @Blake Can a div be set to be unselectable?

Comment: .NameofDiv { 
        -moz-user-select: none; 
        -khtml-user-select: none; 
        -webkit-user-select: none; 
        -o-user-select: none; 
}

Comment: @Baz If any of these answers helped, could you please accept one of them to show that the question has been resolved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a monospaced font for this.*

I basically see two options: 1. use whitespace 2. margins.

#### Option 1

Your text will look like

```
I•am•under•the•text•above
••am•under•••••text•above
```

where `•` denotes a space character. Pretty straight-forward in terms of CSS, since you don't have to worry about the spacing. The browser does it all for you. **Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PYXdr/**

*<sub>well, it may be possible with any font, using a lot of JS, but I guess it's not worth it.</sub>

#### Option 2

Since you probably don't want whitespace in between your spans, you may prefer this:

```
I•am•under•the•text•above
  am•under     text•above
```

Now, the spacing needs to be taken care of manually. Each span should get a `margin-left` that pushes it to the desired position. But before we can do that, we need to know the width of one character (using JS, since CSS does not provide that). Okay, pretty easy:

```js
var el = document.createElement('pre');
el.style.display = 'inline-block';
el.innerHTML = ' ';
document.body.appendChild(el);
var width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el).width);
document.body.removeChild(el);
```

Now let's go ahead and move the spans:

```js
span1.style.marginLeft = (2 * width) + 'px';
span2.style.marginLeft = (5 * width) + 'px';
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JC3Sc/**

#### Putting it all together

Now here's a basic example of how this might work:

```js
var text = "I am under the text above me and there is lots more text to come.\nI am even moving onto a new line since I have more text"

var highlightBorders = [[2, 3, 4, 6], [6, 7]]; // YOUR TASK: implement the logic to display the following lines

var color_per_word_position =  {0:'lime', 1: 'red', 2: 'cyan', 3:'orange', 4: 'yellow', 5: 'red'}

/* generate CSS */
var style = document.createElement('style');
for (var i in color_per_word_position) {
    style.innerHTML += '.hl' + i + '{background:' + color_per_word_position[i] + '}';
}
document.head.appendChild(style);


/* generating the text */
text = text.split('\n');
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
text.forEach(function (line, i) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var words = line.split(' ');
    var result = [];
    highlightBorders[i].forEach(function (len, j) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = words.splice(0, len).join(' ');
        span.className = 'hl' + j;
        if (j) {
            span.style.marginLeft = width + 'px' // YOUR TASK: implement the logic
        }
        div.appendChild(span);
    });
    pre.appendChild(div);
});

document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

This is not a complete solution, since a) I don't really see which parts exactly you want to highlight and b) I don't want to spoil all the fun. But you get the idea.

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tNyqL/**

Comment: You would not have to use a monospaced font if a simple JS function for positioning is used. Also, this would end up being very tedious if the OP has to count pixels.

Comment: @Bagavatu Not sure what you're trying to say. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This method requires the OP to use a monospaced font, since it calculates width based on characters. Also, it requires a pre tag. I'm not sure if this would work with a responsive design either.

Comment: @Bagavatu I certainly mentioned that the same would work with a variable-width font, using more JS. A `pre` tag is not required. Responsive design has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Using padding this is possible but also have absolute control by assigning text to a selector such as "p" for the class: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3NDs3/1/

```
   .one {
    width:200px;
}
.one p {
    font: normal 14px Futura, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:130px;
}
.two {
    width:200px;
}
.two p {
    text-align:center;
    font: normal 14px Futura, sans-serif;
}
.three {
    width:200px
}
.three p {
    text-align:left;
    font: normal 14px Futura, sans-serif;
    padding-left:35px;
}


    <div class="one">
    <p>above me</p>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <p>i am under the text above me</p>
</div>
<div class="three">
    <p>under</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems overly tedious; it requires the OP to type every div by hand and set positioning manually, which is not as feasible for long paragraphs.

Comment: his original post was three sentences with these original words, with chunks of text like this he's better just hiding it, but with lower amounts of text he could achieve it this way.